# Ionic2 - Show/Hide button based on how the controller was shown

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, ionic2, ionic3

I have a page `Page2` which needs to be open sometimes using a `modal()` and sometimes using a `push()`.

In the normal scenario, if the controller is opened using a push method it will show a "Back" button. However, in the other scenario which is opening the page using a `modal()` method, I need to add a close button to `Page2` so the user can dismiss that controller at any time.

**The Problem**

If I add a close button to `Page2` then that button shows even if the controller was opened using a `push()` method and in this case it shows a back button and a close button.

**What I want**

I want to add a condition, in which if the controller was opened using `push()`, then it should hide that close button

**The flow:**

Page 1 > (Push to) > Page 2 (Hide the close button)

Page 3 > (Modal to) > Page 2 (Show the close button)

Any idea on how to achieve that?

Comment: Is it a valid option, if you send a parameter with a false/true value to the page? That way the page could hide/show the button and the only thing you need to do is send the proper parameter when calling the `create` / `push` method.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could send a parameter to the `Page2` constructor, something like this:

```
presentPage2AsModal() {
   let page2Modal = this.modalCtrl.create(Page2, { showCloseBtn: true });
   page2Modal.present();
 }
```

And if you open it with the `push` method:

```
openPage2AsPage() {
   this.nav.push(Page2, { showCloseBtn: false });
 }
```

And then in the `Page2` constructor:

```
constructor(..., private navParams: NavParams) {
    // Get the param
    this.showCloseBtn = navParams.get('showCloseBtn');
}
```

And in the View:

```
<button *ngIf="showCloseBtn" (click)="yourMethod">Close</button>
```

Comment: Genius idea, great explanation!! +1

Comment: Glad to be helpful :)